# Is this Sanae Tsukimoto's older sibling?

Tags: teasing-master-takagi-san

1

From S03E06:

There's someone who looks like Sanae Tsukimoto who is beside

> Tanabe-sensei who is crying.

> [image]

But this can't be Sanae who appears earlier:

[image]

I heard Sanae has an older sibling who teaches in the school. (Or maybe it was actually mentioned in the anime.) So I guess it's Sanae's older sibling. I looked up fandom and it says Sanae's older sibling's anime debut in S03E02...

2

From S03E02 where Nishikata and Takagi are on library duty:

Is this Sanae's older sibling?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For S03E02 yes. From [fandom](https://karakai-jouzu-no-takagi-san.fandom.com/wiki/Episode_2/Season_3):

> The librarian was change into Sanae's sister in the anime.

But I didn't see any mention in [S03E06 fandom](https://karakai-jouzu-no-takagi-san.fandom.com/wiki/Episode_6/Season_3) that Tsukimoto-sensei is in S03E06.

Answer (score 1):

Just finished original series manga. Yes that's her. Tsukimoto-sensei is Sanae Tsukimoto's big sis.